# Encrypted URL sent from Jenkins email plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

Configured Jenkins to send emails after every build run, the email content contains a report URL, it was all working fine from many days but recently what we noticed that the URL in email content is different though once we click on the URL, it shows the proper report something like this.

URL mentioned in the email:
http://IP:8080/job/Test/lastCompletedBuild/reports/overview.html

URL is shown in the actual mail

https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__IP-3A8080_job__overview-2Dfeatures.htm.....

Is there any way I can revert this to send the same URL as configured in default content?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your company installed [Proofpoint's Targeted Attack Protection](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/products/ransomware-and-targeted-attack-protection), hence the rewritten URL points to proofpoint.com. There might be a way to whitelist your Jenkins in Proofpoint, but I'm pretty sure that there is nothing to be done in Jenkins.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i will check with our it team.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your mail server rewriting urls for spam/phishing protection